# emplace_back modify the value in parameter

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code and figured out a problem with emplace_back on vector.

```
void generateTube(std::vector<glm::vec3> &vertices, const glm::vec3 &pos) {
   glm::vec3 N, B;
   float cos, sin;

   ...

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
      ...
      std::cout << pos << std::endl;
      vertices.emplace_back(pos + cos * N + sin * B);
      std::cout << pos << std::endl;
      ...
   }
}
```

The result output :

```
[0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000]
[-1998397155538108416.000000, -1998397155538108416.000000, -1998397155538108416.000000]
```

As you can see the value of pos if modified by emplace_back. If I remove the call, the value is never changed.

Do you have an explanation ?
I use the vs2019 compilator on Windows 10, arch is x86_amd64.

Comment: What if you call `push_back`? It's not like you're taking advantage of in-place creation, you're still building your entire object outside the array.

Comment: Same behavior... And actually pos is taken as a parameter. const glm::vec3 &pos. I'm not supposed to be able to modify it

Comment: `const` is a hint, it doesn't mean you can't overwrite it. The code you wrote works as is, it's the secret code hidden behind those dots that's your problem, most likely memory corruption. Feel free to add a small, compilable, reproducible example that illustrates your problem, this won't get an answer.

Comment: Hard to say anything without a [mcve].

Comment: What does `pos` refer to? Doesn't it refer to an element of `vertices`?

Comment: Yes sure, const is  just an hint. It's just to show that I don't modify it myself.
Yes pos refer to an element of vertices, why ?

Comment: @ErwanDaniel Because emplacing/pushing back into a vector may trigger reallocation, which invalidates iterators/pointers/referecnes to vector elements. Using invalidated `pos` then causes _undefined behavior_ of your program. Note that you can avoid reallocation by _reserving_ vector space, of course, prior to initialization of `pos`.

Comment: Mhhh.. Basic and obvious. Of course, because I call  the function like this : generateTube(vertices, vertices.back()); So of course it take the reference. I like it haha.
Post your answer @DanielLangr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes `pos` refer to an element of `vertices`...

That's the problem. During `emplace_back`, reallocation of vector elements may be triggered, which **invalidates** all iterators/**refernces**/pointers to vector elements, including `pos`. Dereferencing `pos` then causes *undefined behavior*.

A simple remedy might be to `reserve` enough vector space before initializing `pos` parameter, which will make sure that no reallocation happens during function call.